# Pandas unstacking - order of nested columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
    a   b   c   v1  v2
0   a1  b1  c1  1   5
1   a2  b1  c1  2   6
2   a1  b2  c1  3   7
3   a2  b2  c1  4   8
```

**What I want to achieve is this format:**

```
        b1      b2
        v1  v2  v1  v2
a   c   
a1  c1  1   3   5   7
a2  c1  2   4   6   8
```

So, the original data is constructed as follows:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": ["a1", "a2", "a1", "a2"],
    "b": ["b1", "b1", "b2", "b2"],
    "c": ["c1", "c1", "c1", "c1"],
    "v1": [1,2,3,4],
    "v2": [5,6,7,8]
})
```

I then tried to

```
foo.set_index(["a", "b", "c"]).unstack("b")
```

However, this resulted in

```
        v1      v2
        b1  b2  b1  b2
a   c               
a1  c1  1   3   5   7
a2  c1  2   4   6   8
```

Subsequently, my question is how do I make the unstacked *b* column align itself ontop of the value columns instead of below them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = (foo.set_index(["a", "b", "c"]).unstack("b")
         .swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1)
         .rename_axis((None, None), axis=1))
print (df)
      b1    b2   
      v1 v2 v1 v2
a  c             
a1 c1  1  5  3  7
a2 c1  2  6  4  8
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) instead of using `set_index` and `unstack` with `swaplevel`:

```
In [565]: foo.pivot(["a", "c"], columns='b').swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
Out[565]: 
b     b1 b2 b1 b2
      v1 v1 v2 v2
a  c             
a1 c1  1  3  5  7
a2 c1  2  4  6  8
```

For getting your output, you can do this:

```
In [2941]: foo.pivot(["a", "c"], columns='b').swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1).rename_axis((None, None), axis=1)
Out[2941]: 
      b1    b2   
      v1 v2 v1 v2
a  c             
a1 c1  1  5  3  7
a2 c1  2  6  4  8
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was not able to to obtain the exact format I was looking for as the levels of *b* where repeated when I wanted them to occur only once per set of value columns.

Comment: @user3054852 I just gave you a solution suggesting that `set_index` and `unstack` is unnecessary. `Pivot` can be used. And `swaplevel` can be used to bring your `b` up. This can be tweaked.

Comment: I understood so much and I appreciate the alternative solution!